# HTML + JS - File name resets in text when adding a new file button

Tags: javascript, html, file, reset, filechooser

I have a add button, like this, to add more `<input type="file">`:
[image]

And it does work, when I click on the button, it calls a method to add a new file chooser.

## HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="attachments_row">
          <div class="coffee-span-4">
            <label class="label label-1">Attachments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="coffee-span-6" id="attachments">
            <div id="attachment_inner">
                <input id="file_button" type="file" name="fileUpload0" size="50" /> 
                <sf:errors path="filepath" cssClass="rfqerror"></sf:errors>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="+" style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px;" onclick="makeNewAttachment();"/>
          </div>

          <div class="coffee-span-2" id="file-upload-button">
          </div>

          <br>
</div>
```

## JS:

```
function makeNewAttachment() {
    var ai = document.getElementById("attachment_inner").innerHTML;
    var index = document.getElementById("attachment_inner").children.length;
    var ai_new = ai + "<input id='file_button' type='file' name='fileUpload" + index + "' size='50' />";
    document.getElementById("attachment_inner").innerHTML = ai_new;
}
```

But when I choose a file, the file name resets back to `No file chosen`.

## Chose a file:

[image]

## Click add, resets?!?!?!?

[image]

Does anyone know why?! 
I made each name different, I thought that was the case, but nope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're duplicating the HTML text inside the div `#attachment_inner`, not the document objects that are the children of the div object. The text that represents the file-chooser `input` doesn't have an attribute representing the most recently chosen file name. That information is in the `input` object. Although the object was built from HTML text, that text isn't rewritten to reflect new information such as the name of the chosen file.

The solution is to use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to make a deep copy of the object that you want to duplicate.

In the snippet below, I'm cloning the div containing the file chooser so that you also have a copy of the `sf:errors` tag and whatever else you might want to have along with the button. In addition, the container div makes layout easier. To avoid having multiple divs with the same `id`, I changed `id="attachment_inner"` to `class="attachment_inner"`.

```js
function makeNewAttachment() {
    var attachments = document.getElementById('attachments'),
        choosers = attachments.getElementsByClassName('attachment_inner'),
        numChoosers = choosers.length,
        newChooser = choosers[numChoosers - 1].cloneNode(true),
        input = newChooser.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    attachments.insertBefore(newChooser, document.getElementById('plusButton'));
    input.name = input.name.replace(/\d+$/, '' + numChoosers);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="attachments_row">
          <div class="coffee-span-4">
            <label class="label label-1">Attachments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="coffee-span-6" id="attachments">
            <div class="attachment_inner">
                <input type="file" name="fileUpload0" size="50" /> 
                <sf:errors path="filepath" cssClass="rfqerror"></sf:errors>
            </div>
            <input id="plusButton" type="button" value="+" style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px;" onclick="makeNewAttachment();"/>
          </div>

          <div class="coffee-span-2" id="file-upload-button">
          </div>

          <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you've earned +25 rep!

Comment: Thanks, dude. I appreciate it.